# Retrieving secrets from HashiCorp Vault in jenkins pipeline using HashiCorp Vault Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, hashicorp-vault

I have setup a connection between my Jenkins and Vault and by using "withVault" method
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/hashicorp-vault-plugin/#hashicorp-vault-plugin

I am retrieving vault secrets from Vault in my jenkins pipeline. Secret is stored in the environment variable github_token, which is then used to form URL for accessing git in the pipeline. Retrieving secrets works, the problem is, that $github_token variable contains asterisks.

I need it to contain actual value of the the token

```
def secrets = [
    [path: 'ddci/data/test', engineVersion: 2, secretValues: [
        [envVar: 'github_token', vaultKey: 'token']
  ]]     
]

def configuration = [vaultUrl: 'https://vault.tools.sap/',
                     vaultNamespace: 's4',
                     vaultCredentialId: 'hashicorp_vault',
                     skipSslVerification: true,
                     engineVersion: 2]
```

pipeline {
agent any

```
stages{  
stage('use token to authenticate GITHub') { 
    steps {
  withVault([configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
    sh 'git_url= https://username:${github_token}@github.tools.sap/AZURE-PIPELINES-SYSDEV/decdev-ci-verification'
    git url: '$git_url', branch: 'master'
    
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $github_token variable doesn't contain asterisks, Jenkins displays any Vault secret using asterisks on console, to protect the real value.

if you want to check the $github_token value, write it to a file in the workspace, doing something like this:

```
echo $github_token > token.txt
```

Some other problem is preventing you to access the GitHub server (Is the token correct? Is the path correct? Has the Jenkins node access to the GitHub?). Log to the Jenkins node and try to execute the same command manually.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you posted, it appears the URL resources is "not found". This implies an HTTP status code of 404.

Make sure you server URL is correct and that the server is configured to handle dynamically generated URLs - the token will likely be different every time, unless of course you are using some caching mechanism and you have some refresh token portion of your script.
Personally I would use One-time Tokens (OTP), but of course, this would depend on your security requirements.
Best of luck.